# SVG: Path: Moveto (M) is relative from origin not absolute to the grid

Tags: svg, path, absolute

I have a really major problem.

lets say:

viewbox="0 0 50 50"

```
<circle id="circle1_1"  cx="25" cy="25" r="1" opacity="1" fill="#FF0000">
    <animateMotion
        dur="5s"
        path="M -10 -10 C 30 20, 40 50, 25 25"
    />
</circle>
```

Now the Problem:

And the thing is: M is uppercase, so I have no clue why it doesnt work..

Instead of moving to -10,-10 in the Viewbox, it is moving to 15,15 what equals (25 - 10), (25 -10)...

I'm absolutely clueless what I shall do here... I just want the circle to start at -10 -10 (in my project anywhere outside the viewbox) and end it at 25, 25 and stay there...

the starting position is generated with random_int, and I generated a bunch of circles...

How can I achieve that Moveto (M) will take the absolute coordinate and not the relative one?

Comment: set cx and cy to 0 perhaps.

Comment: A path in animateMotion represents a set of transforms & as such is an offset to the position of the element you're animating. You can't set it to an absolute point (you can use Javascript to do that.)

Comment: solved it... I just gave it no position and make an animation for 999h repeating after the first animation and Move it to the Final position

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
<circle id="circle3_1" r="10" opacity="1" fill="#FF0000">
    <animateMotion
        dur="5"
        path="MStartX StartY C -101 -1010,-195 141, FinalX FinalY"
        fill="freeze"/>
</circle>
```

Comment: don't you just want fill="freeze" in the first and then drop the second animateMotion.

Comment: fill="freeze"? never heared that before

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-smil-animation-20010904/#Fill

Comment: Makes the .svg size about 30% smaller